# API Negatif Scenario with Rest-Assured and Junit

Tags: rest-assured

I want to make an API negative test scenario with Rest-Assured Library. I'm creating a get request for a data that doesn't exist. When I print this response to the console, I want to see the text 'not found' Because postman says this is the request body. But my test failed on get method. I am getting that error

`io.restassured.internal.http.HttpResponseException: status code: 404, reason phrase: Not Found`

Actually I know the status code is 404. But I can not test about it. How can i write that negative scenario

```
Response response = given().
                            when().
                                get("https://restful-booker.herokuapp.com/booking/1001");
```

Comment: I don't see any problem with your code. I've tested it, it printed `Not Found` as expected. `System.out.println(response.asString());`

Comment: Yes the code worked fine for some of my friends. But i still get that error, i can not solve it

Comment: so pls add pull code and stack trace, pom.xml (if available).

Comment: I checked my pom.xml file. Exactly like that;

Comment: `   <dependencies>

        <!-- https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/io.rest-assured/rest-assured -->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>io.rest-assured</groupId> 
            <artifactId>rest-assured</artifactId>
            <version>4.5.1</version>
            <scope>test</scope>
        </dependency>

        <!-- https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/junit/junit -->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>junit</groupId>
            <artifactId>junit</artifactId>
            <version>4.13.2</version>
            <scope>test</scope>
        </dependency>`

Comment: `    <!-- https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.testng/testng -->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.testng</groupId>
            <artifactId>testng</artifactId>
            <version>7.5</version>
            <scope>test</scope>
        </dependency>


        <!-- https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.json/json -->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.json</groupId>
            <artifactId>json</artifactId>
            <version>20211205</version>
        </dependency>

     `

Comment: ` <!-- https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/com.fasterxml.jackson.core/jackson-databind -->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.fasterxml.jackson.core</groupId>
            <artifactId>jackson-databind</artifactId>
            <version>2.13.1</version>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.google.code.gson</groupId> 
            <artifactId>gson</artifactId>
            <version>2.9.0</version>
        </dependency>
      
       `

Comment: ` <dependency>
            <artifactId>jackson-mapper-asl</artifactId>
            <version>1.9.13</version>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.codehaus.jackson</groupId>
            <artifactId>jackson-core-asl</artifactId>
            <version>1.9.13</version>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.junit.jupiter</groupId>
            <artifactId>junit-jupiter</artifactId>
            <version>RELEASE</version>
            <scope>test</scope>
        </dependency>


    </dependencies>

</project>'`

Comment: Please revise your question, comment is not a place to put information.